# Changes in /etc/network/interfaces do not make any change

Tags: networking, network-manager

I config static ip in /etc/network/interfaces

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.121
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

and restart eth0 interface

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

but the eth0 interface doesn't change.

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e6:ba:22:6a:f2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92e6:baff:fe22:6af2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7908 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5452712 (5.4 MB)  TX bytes:1534077 (1.5 MB)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0x4000
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the command: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: It didnt work for me and rebooted instead ... however I think that http://askubuntu.com/a/333100/289062 will work