# restart network interface after editing /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager

restart the network service:

```
service networking restart
```

When I give the above command I get something like

```
stop: Unknown instance:
networking stop/waiting
```

I would like to know if the network services has restarted or is it showing some errors. if it is an error how to rectify it?

Comment: @DavidFoerster this post has been nearly 3x times as that one, and the answers there seem to be of similar quality, so why close this one instead of that?

Comment: @muru: All the answers given here also exist on the linked question. We could also merge the questions which is what I requested through a mod flag.

Answer (score 83):

After editing /etc/network/interfaces, the usual way to get the system to re-read the file and use the changes is to do:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0
```

Of course, substitute the relevant interface if it's not wlan0.

I assume Network Manager is not present on this system. If it is, you are better off to make your changes there rather than /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: If within a local network managed by a firewall like shorewall, then most likely your network cards, eth0 and eth1, will have internal ip addresses, so will look something like: sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0

Comment: NetworkManager isn't always could help. I.e. for unknown reasons my NetworkManager just ignores even a network existence(a network doesn't react on any change in the NetworkManager). Also I had a negative experience with NetworkManager in the fact that if a network was broken(relatively often thing in the case of my ISP), it doesn't even tell a reason. When I am configure manually I at least know that I can peek at a log file.

Comment: sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0                                                               /etc/network  
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: @DavidOkwii Please start your own new question and include your details.

Comment: Good to know: if you're at a server restarting that same interface you are using it's NOT closing your connection (if your interface is configured ok, I guess). You are safe.

Comment: I get `zsh: command not found: ifdown` on Ubuntu 20_04. I normally use Network Manager but want to try `allow-hotplug` to detect a plugged lan cable automatic in my usb network adapter

Comment: @Timo In 20.04 the /etc/network/interfaces process is deprecated in favor of netplan. Please see the templates here: /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples If you need further guidance, please post your own new question.

Answer (score 33):

Please be aware that starting with Ubuntu Server 16.04, you need to use the `ip` command to flush the interface address before restarting networking, otherwise changes in the interfaces file will not take effect.

**IMPORTANT:** If you are doing this through an SSH connection, it's important that you chain the commands together as shown below, because you **may** lose the connection to the server immediately after you flush the network interface.

```
sudo ip addr flush interface-name && sudo systemctl restart networking
```

([Source](http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-restart-network-interface/))

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 it seems that it should now be `sudo ip addr flush $ifname && sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`