# How to configure ip static in Ubuntu Server 16.04 running in Hyper-V

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, ip, static-ip

I've configured a Static IP in Ubuntu Server, but when I do an `ifconfig -a` I don't see the new IP.

I must reload the new IP?

My configuration:

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

And finally

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

But I don`t see the new IP, I see 192.168.1.16

`ifconfig -a`

[image: Response ifconfig -a]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [restart network interface after editing /etc/network/interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/333063/restart-network-interface-after-editing-etc-network-interface)

Comment: What do you see in `ifconfig -a` post the output

Comment: @chili555 I think that is different.

Comment: @meccooll Img with the response in the first post.

Comment: How is it different? Do you get the request IP address if you do: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`? Check: `ifconfig`

Comment: @chili555 Because I can`t do this command, when I do this, I view an error.

Comment: I fix the issue. 1- Restarting all server. 2 - Clean and writting the eth0 static configuration. 3 - executing the command  /etc/init.d/networking restart.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Restarting all server.
2. Clean and writing the `eth0` static configuration.
3. Executing the command `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.